# How to set permissions dynamically in Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.FacebookAuthorize?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-c#-sdk

### **Controller**

```
public partial class HomeController
{
     private static String[] userPermissions;
     public HomeController()
     {
          var MyPermission = Convert.ToString(TempData["MyPermission"]);
          userPermissions = (MyPermission).Split(',');
     }

     [Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.FacebookAuthorize(userPermissions)]
     public virtual ActionResult MyActionMethod()
     {
         return View();
     }
}
```

### **Overload**

[image]

### **Compilation Error**

In the above block, we have following code

```
[Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.FacebookAuthorize(userPermissions)]
```

*It is giving below compilation error...*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps but this is how I let users add additional permissions.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Use this method when an action fails due to lack of priviligies. It will redirect user to facebook with provided permission request.
    /// Refactor to handle list of request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="permission"></param>
    private static void AddAdditionalPermissions(string permission)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation(permission + " not authorized for user.");
        string facebook_urlAuthorize_base = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize";
        string scope = permission; //see: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ for extended permissions
        string urlAuthorize = facebook_urlAuthorize_base;
        urlAuthorize += "?client_id=" + AppId;
        urlAuthorize += "&redirect_uri=" + "https://mydomainnamehere.nu/";
        urlAuthorize += "&scope=" + scope;

        //redirect the users browser to Facebook to ask the user to authorize our Facebook application
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(urlAuthorize, true); //this cannot be done using WebRequest since facebook may need to show dialogs in the users browser
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It is my understanding that you cannot dynamically assign anything to an attribute argument (as the error message backups up).

I do something with my Custom Membership Provider that I think you could adapt to meet your goal. I wanted a roles/rights setup defining user access to various parts of the system without needing to assign a bunch of individual rights to the users but still have very granular control of what each role can do. I followed the approach [**here**](http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/implementing-custom-membership-provider-and-role-provider-for-authenticating-asp-net-mvc-applications) (with some changes) to accomplish this.

The approach I would take if there is a need to do this on the fly in your scenario is define a constant `Role` to use in the `FacebookAuthorize` attribute for an `ActionMethod` and then in whatever is handling your permission checking pass (or have it look up) the array of `permissions` for each "role". This way the "role" you assign to the `AuthorizeAttribute` is a constant.

Comment: The page you linked to is dead, nd what's directly in your answer lacks detail :(

Comment: Please, update the link that no longer works and provide a mimimum information about what the linked page says.

Comment: @Alexei The link is still working for me, and provides detailed implementation approach as an example to what I did, not necessarily an answer to his question, for which my recommendation in paragraph three is still valid.

Comment: @Matthew - when I have checked, it was not working (404). Now, it works.